# Syntax for stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and explanation

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to run a readability javascript and I'm not sure how to use the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to run it on a html to be displayed within a webview.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The argument you pass is the JavaScript to be executed. The code's return value is the string returned by the method. You'll need to know a bit of JavaScript to do anything with this method.